# How do I use slide inside TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\DatabaseQueryProcessor

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I can not use CONTENTs slide with TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\DatabaseQueryProcessor

```
page {
    1 {
        dataProcessing { 
            # Content inside right column
            1 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\DatabaseQueryProcessor
            1 {
                table = tt_content
                slide = -1
                where = colPos = 1

                as = contentrightcolumn
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I expect slide to work inside TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\DatabaseQueryProcessor but it is not working.

Why is it not working? It looks like, that it is not implemented.

How can I easily achieve CONTENT slide behavior?

Comment: What's your goal?

Slide is not implemented, that's correct. Depending on your goal, there are different ways to get there.

Comment: My goal is to show content of the right column with DatabaseQueryProcessor. I have many pages with a lot of content inherited in the right column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use slide inside DatabaseQueryProcessor, but you could write your own dataprocessor.

You can use the following typoscript. This should give you the same result inside **contentrightcolumn**. Maybe this is not the best solution but you get your results.

```
page {
    1 {
        dataProcessing {
            # Content inside right column
            1 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\DatabaseQueryProcessor
            1 {
                table = tt_content

                uidInList {
                    # this cObject creates a csv of all contents inside your colPos 1
                    cObject = CONTENT
                    cObject {
                        table = tt_content
                        slide = -1
                        select.where = colPos = 1
                        select.orderBy = sorting

                        renderObj = TEXT
                        renderObj {
                            field = uid
                            wrap = |,
                        }
                    }

                    stdWrap.substring = 0,-1
                }

                where = colPos = 1
                # otherwise the sorting would be wrong
                orderBy = sorting
                # considering the uid of you root page is 1
                pidInList = 1
                # depth of levels inside your pagetree
                recursive = 5

                as = contentrightcolumn
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this just did it.

Answer (score 0):

There are different concepts within TypoScript.

One concept is to **ENRICH** data before rendering with `FLUIDTEMPLATE`. This is done using DataProcessors.

But there is another way to **ADD** data to `FLUIDTEMPLATE`. This option is called `variables`. There can be as many variables as data processors attached to a single `FLUIDTEMPLATE`.

In case you wanna output rendered content within your `FLUIDTEMPLATE`, I would go with a variable:

```
page {
    1 {
        variables {
            contentrightcolumn = CONTENT
            contentrightcolumn {
                table = tt_content
                slide = -1
                select {
                    where = colPos = 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This provides a new variable containing the rendered HTML. Output can be done using:

```
{contentrightcolumn -> f:format.raw()}
```

which might open XSS issues, depending on rendering chain. But in most cases this should be the solution.

Also:

```
{contentrightcolumn -> f:format.html()}
```

is possible, but might not result in your expectation as some tags might be modified.

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/ContentObjects/Fluidtemplate/Index.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer but contentrightcolumn is a string? I can not use the for each inside my fluid template.

Comment: Right, because you already have the rendered content. Otherwise you would need to define how to render content within your page layout.

Comment: Okay. Maybe I do understand. But how do I define other layouts, templates and partials to the right column, when using variables approach. I just do not get it. ):

Comment: You can use multiple variables, e.g. page.1.variables.contentleftcolumn and use constraint to a different colPos. I don't get the idea behind binding templates, partials or layouts to a colPos. Maybe you can just write what you wanna achieve on a different level then technical?

Comment: But the rendering is complete different than main content. FSC is used in main but I do not want this in side right column. I can put a lot of condtions inside FSC tempaltes/layouts/partials but this is just too much work.